# Method cannot be applied to given type

Tags: java

```
public class HurdalQuentonA2Q1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    double kgs ;

    double lbs ;

    double convertLBtoKG = convertLBtoKG(kgs, lbs) ;

  }
  static double convertLBtoKG(double lbs) {

    return lbs * 0.454 ; 


  }

  static double readWeight() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in) ;
    System.out.println("Enter your preferred system of weight measurement, k(for kg) or, p(for lb)") ;
    String userinput = input.nextLine() ;
      if(userinput == "p") {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        System.out.println("Enter your dog's weight in lbs") ;
         double lbs = keyboard.nextDouble() ; 
          double kgs = convertLBtoKG ;
```

upon compilation an error pops up stating

```
method convertLBtoKG in class HurdalQuentonA2Q1 cannot be applied to given types
required: double
found: double,double
```

I have no clue whats causing this

Comment: Well, what do you think it means when it says it **requires** double and **found** double, double, and your method sig is `convertLBtoKG(double lbs)` and you call it like this: `convertLBtoKG(kgs, lbs)`?

Comment: You're trying to call a function that doesn't exist - you need to pass in the right number of parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `convertLBtoKG` method:

```
static double convertLBtoKG(double lbs) {
```

is defined as a method that needs one `double` parameter (`double lbs`) and returns a `double` (the `double` after the word `static`).  To use it, you have to call it in a way that's consistent with the profile: give it one `double` parameter, and then do something with the value of the method call, which will be what the method returns.  Thus, instead of

```
double convertLBtoKG = convertLBtoKG(kgs, lbs) ;
```

you want

```
lbs = convertLBtoKG(kgs);  // THIS IS STILL WRONG, SEE BELOW
```

(don't say `double lbs = ...` since you already declared `double lbs;` earlier).

Also, you will need to assign something to `kgs` before you use it in the method call.

**EDIT:** Although I tried to fix the line that was giving you the error, it's totally wrong, and it doesn't belong there.  The code that actually does the conversion is in `readWeight`, but you never call `readWeight`.  You need to add something to `main` that calls it.  Then, in `readWeight`, instead of this line:

```
      double kgs = convertLBtoKG ;
```

this is where you would want to call the convert method:

```
      double kgs = convertLBtoKG(lbs);
```

I think you need to study carefully how the flow of a program works.  Your `main` program has to call `readWeight` in order to get the code in `readWeight` called; the language doesn't automatically wire things together because you've put `convertLBtoKG` in both `main` and `readWeight`.

Answer (score 1):

`convertLBtoKG` method has only 1 parameter, but you are calling it with 2 parameters.

```
static double convertLBtoKG(double lbs)
```

change your method call to:

```
double convertLBtoKG = convertLBtoKG(lbs) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function declaration for convertLBtoKG only allows one parameter to be passed, but you are passing both lbs and kgs.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in two `double` values to a method which is only accepting a single `double` argument. Either overload the method to create one which accepts two doubles, or call it with the appropriate arguments.

Comment: You mean overload, not override.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods get only 1 parameter double.
But you called **convertLBtoKG(kgs, lbs)** 2 parameter in here.

Answer (score 0):

upon compilation, the compiler will try to match the number of parameters and their type. In this case, you are calling with two parameters but accepting only one.